How do I programmatically validate a go structure that has kubebuilder validation markers?
Say I have the following structure with kubebuilder validation markers:
type ToySpec struct {
    // +kubebuilder:validation:MaxLength=15
    // +kubebuilder:validation:MinLength=1
    Name string `json:"name,omitempty"`
}

I want to do something like this:
spec  = ToySpec{Name: ""}
err := Validate(spec) // Should return error as  name has length of 0

Is this currently possible?

When you put a validation marker for a field, the validation phase is applied automatically and the controller throws error when you create or update the field if the rule is not satisfied. If you want to fetch this error, you should implement a validation function instead of using markers.
To define a function for validating webhook, edit the validation function which is auto-generated by Kubebuilder under api.
func (r *Toy) ValidateCreate() error {
    toylog.Info("validate create", "name", r.Name)

    err := r.checkNameLength()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    return nil
}

func (r *Toy) checkNameLength() error {
    
    // check length
    // process error
    
    return nil
}


First of all you need to import metav1:
import (
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

Then you can test your ToySpec like this:
package controllers

import (
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
)

func TestToySpecValidation(t *testing.T) {
    // Test for Name field exceeding MaxLength
    toy := &ToySpec{
        Name: "ThisNameIsTooLongToPassValidation",
    }
    err := toy.Validate()
    assert.Error(t, err, "Expected validation error for Name exceeding MaxLength")

    // Test for Name field below MinLength
    toy.Name = ""
    err = toy.Validate()
    assert.Error(t, err, "Expected validation error for Name below MinLength")

    // Test case for valid Name field
    toy.Name = "ValidName"
    err = toy.Validate()
    assert.NoError(t, err, "Expected no validation error for valid Name")
}


The Toy structure does not have the validate method, and why are you propsoing ot import metav1?
